# Treat user entered value as thousands in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel:

[image]

I have pre-calculated values that my script calculates and other values are entered by hand, at the moment I am using format `'#,##0.0,'` to make numbers appear in thousands.

Is it possible that when a user inputs `30` in to a cell excel would treat it as `30,000`?
Since everything is in thousands I wish that when a user enters `30` it would mean `30,000` and he wouldn't need to type those extra zeros?

So that instead of the `sum` being `150,030` it would be `180,000` which will then be formatted to `180.0`?

Comment: So multiply the cell value_2 by 1000

Comment: How can I multiply the cell by a 1000 and not have a circular reference to a cell which I am referencing? Like I cant state `C3 = C3 * 1000`

Comment: Reference the cell next to it.

Comment: How can I reference next cell which will hold different value than I need?

Comment: Well, if value_2 is in cell B5 (contains 30 at the moment), then in cell C5 I would put =B5*1000. However you might need to wrap that in an if() in case the user puts 30000 instead of 30... Then your other formulae can call cell C5 instead of B5.

Comment: I have different value in C5 which also needs to be interpreted the same way so I can't and don't want to use references to other cells.

Comment: There must be other empty cells, or have you managed to use all of them?

Comment: That is not the problem I am trying to solve, my goal is clearly defined in the question.

Comment: Your goal is most likely unachievable (unless you are open to code). The solution is to be consistent in both underlying value and number format. Also, how is this a *programming* question?

Comment: I am happy to use code but I do not use excel that much, I do everything in Python but this is where Python ends and excel begins, so I am just wondering if there is a solution